# Fix jQuery UI and Bootstrap tooltip conflict

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm designing a form using Bootstrap.
I have an element that I have applied `.sortable` to:

```
$(function() {
  $('#field_wrapper').sortable({
    placeholder: "drop"
  });
$('#field_wrapper').disableSelection();
});
```

I want to apply a Bootstrap tooltip to the element but have discovered a conflict in the jQuery with:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Is it possible to use both?

Comment: what do you mean conflict in jQuery? are you getting any error? what's that error?

Comment: I mean the tooltip doesn't work...

Comment: where's the tooltip code? could you make a small demo in jsfiddle?

Comment: `<div class="tooltip-demo"><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-container = "body" title="Move"><i class = "fa fa-sort"></i></span></div>` **jQuery**`$('.tooltip-demo').tooltip({
        selector: "[data-toggle=tooltip]",
        container: "body"
    })

    // popover demo
    $("[data-toggle=popover]")
        .popover()`

Comment: It's ok, I think I've fixed it...I moved the script link higher up my header and it all works fine now. :)

Comment: let me guess you had your `bootstrap.js` referenced before `jquery`?

Comment: Yep! Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 2):

I had also face this problem recently. I also want to load the bootstrap tooltip but instead the jquery UI tooltip loaded. I have also searched and finally  one simple solution that works for me that is just put the jquery-ui.js  just above the bootstrap.js and proper.js

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix is to rename the Bootstrap tooltip function name (non-minified code) as follows:

```
/**
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Constants
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

var NAME$6 = 'tooltip';
```

Change `NAME$6` to a unique name, example:

```
var NAME$6 = 'bsTooltip';
```

Then reference as `$.bsTooltip(options)`.